# Como puedo obtener el primer valor de varias tablas relacionadas entre si

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT pr.nombre AS 'nombrePrograma',pr.id 
FROM programas pr
JOIN cursos ON pr.id = cursos.programa_id 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: el registro mas reciente o al mas antiguo?

Comment: y cual es la columna por la cual quieres hacer ese orden?

Comment: puedes agrega pr.nombre DESC; para que muestre el mas reciente!

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que muestras es correcta pero esta incompleta, deberías de probar de este modo

```
SELECT pr.nombre AS 'nombrePrograma',pr.id 
FROM programas pr
JOIN cursos ON pr.id = cursos.programa_id 
ORDER BY pr.nombre DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Al usar `ORDER BY` estas indicando que del dataset de resultados lo ordene por la columna `pr.nombre` y al indicarle de manera `DESC` hará el ordenamiento de este modo

**Si tengo estos registros**

```
Nombre
______
Alfredo
Daniel
Julio
Pedro
Beto
```

**EL RESULTADO DEBERÍA SER ASÍ**

```
Nombre
______
Alfredo
Beto
Daniel
Julio
Pedro
```

Ahora si deseas que el ordamiento se haga del registro hecho mas reciente, entonces usa la columna que tengas registrada por id; yolo haría de este modo

```
SELECT pr.nombre AS 'nombrePrograma',pr.id 
FROM programas pr
JOIN cursos ON pr.id = cursos.programa_id 
ORDER BY pr.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

> Al manejar el ordenamiento por la columna `id` que es o debería ser
>   una llave primaria te devolverá el último registro hecho y al
>   combinarlo con `LIMIT 1` solo mostrará un registro final

Comment: @shadow..muchas gracias como puedo hacer si  tengo varias tablas como: curso-semestre-nivel-modulo-unidad, seria decirle a cada tabla que traiga su primer registro con respecto a su id, la cardinalidad va de la derecha a la izquierda

Comment: @hostLondoñoempezar si tienes todas esas tablas relacionadas solo deberás indicar por cual columna vas a querer que se ordenen así como de que tabla proviene y limitar la cantidad de registros; ya que si estas usando `JOIN` es por que varias tablas estan vinculadas por alguna columna en especifico

Comment: Ajam , la relaciono por id ,la idea es crear una vista o nose que me recomiendas si crear un procedimiento  , que capture todos esos valores existentes y asigne a un usuario con id para que se guarde cada vez que accede un usuario nuevo